# How do I add a fingerprint driver for Ubuntu (dual-boot) on a Windows 11 Lenovo Thinkbook 15-IIL?

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, lenovo, fingerprint-reader

How do I add a fingerprint driver for Ubuntu (dual-boot) on a Windows 11 Lenovo Thinkbook 15-IIL?

I followed through with some command line steps before, and it didn't seem to help. The command line showed that the last step (on the online guide, not the command line (line(s))) didn't find the files it was looking for.

I contacted Lenovo support on their website, and the live chat suggested I talk to software support. I didn't pay for that. I am not going to get that.

So, my next step was to do some research. That kinda failed.

So, now I am on to chat forums. Lenovo and Ubuntu chat forums are two concepts-to-be-tackled kind-of-thing now. But, I am starting with Ubuntu.

Comment: Looks like your laptop comes with Goodix fingerprint drivers. Currently it has limited support in Ubuntu. Even if you manage to install it, the fingerprint recognition can be very slow.

Comment: @ArjunKShibu, 
Do you suggest any better operating systems? 
I couldn't get Zorin OS to load, for example (and it kept making it hard to remove from the USB drives (or even recover (or: format) the USB drives to a usable state) after burning Zorin OS to the USB drives. It turned out I just had to use Ubuntu to format the USB drives instead.).

Comment: After Ubuntu I prefer Zorin OS, Since that didn't turn up well for you, I recommend Linux Mint, Elementary OS, MX Linux or POP_OS!(Haven't tried).